# Is TryParse a bad idea when using a DataReader?

Tags: c#, casting, datareader

So, I have been reading through some code saw an interesting pattern for parsing data from a data reader. It looks like:

```
public static long ParseLong(IDataReader reader, string field, long default)
{
    long result;
    var value = GetValue(reader, field);
    if (value == DBNull.Value) return default;

    // is this next line bad?
    if (Int64.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result)) return result;
    return default;
}
```

This pattern doesn't sit right with me because it hides type casting exceptions and it seems like converting to a string then casting again would be slower than just calling "Convert.ToInt64(value)".

Am I off base in this? Is there a better pattern for parsing data from a data reader?

**Note** - In my case, the type of the column is "NUMBER(20)". Even if this wasn't the case though, it would be better to throw the exception so the developer will fix the issue before going to production, right?

Comment: What are your requirements for parsing? Is it valid to skip over malformed data?

Comment: These lines seems more a fix for a bad designed datatable, where long values are stored in a string field and then require an accurate parsing to avoid errors. If the fields are correctly defined as Long then there is no need to TryParse them, just a conversion is enough (of course the null check still stands)

Comment: Are you storing numeric data in character fields? If not, then `value` should already be a long if it isn't null.

Comment: Actually this particular code base uses inline sql (parameterized). So the only reason the code should break is if the type of a column changed or the inline sql was changed.

Comment: `IDataReader` has a method to read a value as a long [IDataRecord.GetInt64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getint64(v=vs.110).aspx) why would you not just use that? your approach results in boxing the long to an object, then unboxing it to create a long again.

You can use the [IDataRecord.IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) method to check if the value is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's bad.

If the column is already one of the sql number types, this is not only the slow way to do it, but it can introduce bugs if the machine's number format uses some strange separator characters. If you know the column is already a number, you should just cast it to `long`.

On the other hand, there's no context available to this method. From the method's perspective, that column could be anything. And in fact, it's fairly common to find databases designed by people who want to use string types (nvarchar, etc) for everything, however misguided that may be. This code does have a small advantage in that it can still work if the column is using a string type to hold numeric data, and it would be fair to allow a method that wanted to be truly generic to use this technique (though I personally might want to try casting first and then fallback to the string technique only if the cast fails).

However, there is another issue in this code: the DBNull check. **If** you're going to convert to a string and parse it, the null check is redundant. DBNull.Value.ToString() returns an empty string, which will fail the TryParse() call and result in returning the default long, same as the check would. The code is just not needed.

Therefore, we're now in a situation where it's either bad because of the string conversion, or if you allow the string conversion it's bad because of the null check. It fails either way. The only reason I would accept this code is if you can show that you do need the string conversion, and after profiling you find that the program is spending a lot of time needlessly converting DBNull to a string. Then adding the faster null check would be okay.

I do have one point in defense of this code, based on your edit. A quick check of the [docs for the long type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) show that the max value for a long tops out at 19 digits. You're storing up to 20. So this code *could* be there in an attempt to protect against very large values between 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 and 99,999,999,999,999,999,999 that do fit in the column but don't fit within the long type... though even in this case, my preference would be to throw an exception for those values, rather than just returning 0.

One last thought. This code works because `IDataReader` implements the `IDataRecord` interface. The method should just ask for an `IDataRecord`, to make it more flexible.

Comment: I appreciate the thought out answer. You took this a similar direction to what I was thinking but brought up a number of other really good points. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason parse value through string, because it can hide data error.
You cen use generics variant of your method:

```
public static T Parse<T>(IDataReader reader, string field, T default)
{
    int columnIndex = reader.GetOrdinal(field);
    if (reader.IsDBNull(columnIndex)) return default;    
    return (T)reader.GetValue(columnIndex);
}
```

`IDataRecord` interface provide you type specific read than you can read with the `IDataRecord.GetInt64` method, but you have to check to DBNull as well.